# Анимация "уплывающего" текста при клике на span

Tags: jquery

Имеется форма для отправки запроса

```
<form name="search" action="/search" method="POST">
<input type="text" id="searchText" name="searchText">
<button id="submit" type="submit"></button>
</form>
```

Далее на странице текст, каждое слово которого обрамлено тегами , например:

```
<span class="word">Жил</span> <span class="word">на</span> <span class="word">свете</span> <span class="word">пёс</span>....
```

(это пока мои домыслы как оформить слова в тексте для использования анимации).

При клике на любое слово, нужна анимация, будто это слово "улетает" на форму в поле ввода и по пути растворяется. Как это сделать? )

Comment: C jQuery это кажется простой задачей. Поделитесь своей попыткой, а я поделюсь своей, ок?

Comment: к сожалению не владею навыками работы с jquery